# xpath syntax for semi-joins

Tags: xpath

I know that I can use xpath to perform joins using the "|" operator. Is there a way to perform semi-joins in xpath like for example:

```
book[author = article/author]/title
```

If semi-joins exist, what would the output of the query above look like. Does it just output the title element of each book that has an author who also authored an article?

Comment: Yes, the xpath expression will answer what you've written (but note that the book elements have to be child of the context node).

Comment: In XPath "|" is a union operator, not a join operator. Which makes me want to know exactly what you mean by semi-join. Importing the language of relational algebra operators is not necessarily appropriate, since the data model is completely different the operators will also differ.

Comment: I'm sorry I abused the notation. I wasn't sure how such a query would be called (Is there a proper name?). The query I described is similar to what a semi-join in relational algebra would do so that's why I called it a semi-join. I want to return all book titles where the author of the book is the same as the author of an (any) article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want `//book[author = //article/author]/title`. With your current attempt `book[author = article/author]` the `article` elements would need to be children of the `book` element which does not seem likely.

Comment: You are right. I meant books and articles to be on the same level. Each article/book has an author child. 

So is /book[author = /article/author]/title the proper syntax?

Comment: @Mathias, No.  That will never return anything, because it relies on the document node having two child elements, which is impossible.  Use the example given by Martin.

Comment: You are right Paul, thanks. The operation is probably going to be expensive though ( O(n*m) if there are n books and m articles ).

Answer (score 0):

The given query would return the title of each book that contains an article that has been authored by that book's author.  Thus, in the context of `books` below, the only thing returned would be the `title` element with the text "title 0".

```
<books>    
 <book>
   <title>Title 0</title>
   <author>Petri, M</author>
   <article>
     <title>Title 1</title>
     <author>Petri, M</author>
   </article>
   <article>
     <title>Title 2</title>
     <author>Butcher, P</author>
   </article>
 </book>

 <book>
    <title>Title 3</title>
    <author>Butcher, P</author>
    <article>
      <title>Title 4</title>
      <author>Petri, M</author>
    </article>
 </book>
</books>
```